# Set multiple collections of beans using a Java Beans Datasource

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource, javabeans

I need to show two charts in the same *JasperReports*'s report, one showing data with products and another with persons.

Usually, I can define a factory class that returns a single collection of beans, for example the products data beans. Can I make available to the report the two collections of beans?

I can't use subreports and I need to use a Java Beans datasource.

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't know if you still need this answer, but maybe others will need.

You don't really need two collection of beans but a combination into one by creating a helperClass, lets say Products_Person_Class then add the instance variables of the fields you need (don't forget the getters and setters) Then set the variables for instances in another Class;

For example, lets says you need two fields in your report. One from Person data and another from Product data (fields are PersonId and ProductId)

You make your helper class

```
public class Products_Person{
    private String personId;
    private String productId; 


  //make sure you have a constructor

  public Products_Person(){

  }

  public String getPersonId(){
    return personId;
   }

  public String setPersonId(String personId){
   this.personId = personId; 

  //do the same for productId

  }
```

Then in another Class set your variables:

```
 //lets use hard code numbers for simplicity
  Products_Person p = new Products_Person();
  p.setPersonId("011111");
  p.setProductId("5555");
```

Then add such to a List of type Products_Person

```
List<Products_Person> list = new ArrayList<Product_Person>();

list.add(p.getPersonId());
list.add(p.getProductId());
```

So in your Collection you will have:

```
public Collection<Products_Person> getBeanDataSource(){
   return list;
```

Then in your report you will be able to see such fields or perhaps put the data in a   chart

```
   $F(personId)
   $F(productId)
```